# Sms broadcast receiver not always triggered

Tags: android, android-studio, sms, samsung-mobile

I have a problem in receiving sms via **broadcast receiver**. About a year ago I wrote an application that among other things also read sms, it has always worked without particular problems on all devices except the last one on which I installed.
The phone in question is a **Samsung A20e** on which **Android version 11** is installed, the application for some reason only receives some of the sms that the phone receives, the strangest thing is that it seems not to work only with sms coming from some contacts and not with all.

For example, I have never been able to receive a broadcast upon receiving an SMS sent from my personal number even after many attempts, while I also receive them on the first try if the SMS comes from other numbers. Unfortunately, this behavior is repeated for other phone numbers apparently without logic.

This is the declaration of the receiver inside the manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".utility.broadcastreceiver.SmsReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Instead, these are the permissions that I have set regarding sms:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Which are also requested at runtime:

```
public static final String[] PERMISSIONS = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,
        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
        Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
};
//...
public static void requestPermission(Context ctx, Activity activity) {
    if (!(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M))
        return;
    if (!hasPermissions(ctx, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                PERMISSIONS, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

I also tried to register the receiver at runtime (always with the highest priority):

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS);
    filter.setPriority(2147483647);
    SmsReceiver receiver = new SmsReceiver();
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

The problem does not seem to derive from the application itself since it works with some numbers, while with others the reciver is never triggered, so I think that it may depend on some other application installed on the phone. As a sms application I use messages by google (and not the default one that was installed, with which I always had the same problem).

The only other applications that use permissions for reading sms are: Bixby Service, Messages and Phone.

Can I check if there is actually another application that is interfering with mine? Or if it depends on something else related to the phone or my application?

Comment: Are you sure those messages are actually SMS? Can you list those missed messages afterward by querying the SMS Provider; e.g., `getContentResolver().query(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, ...);`? Many (most?) modern messaging clients will seamlessly integrate SMS with MMS, RCS, whatever, so you can't really tell a difference by just looking at the app. Also, modern clients can switch between protocols silently depending on certain things; e.g., the particular contact, etc. You might have a look through your messaging apps' settings to see if they're supporting RCS, or Advanced Messaging, or similar.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the reply and the help, actually the problem was that the message application had enabled the chat mode and therefore the messages that arrived on the phone were not sms even if they appeared to be so. Thanks again